# Moving strokes between InkCanvas with background color change of only the strokes? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, inkcanvas

Lets say I have three layers (from bottom to top),

1. InkCanvas (the lowest z level),
2. InkCanvas (used for writing),
3. InkCanvas ( the highest z level, on top, used for drawing).

In MVVM (WPF), how can capture of strokes from the highest z-level be moved to the lowest level z-level? (When moved, the bounding rectangle of the strokes is to be filled with a Yellow color. That is, the background color of *only* the area enclosing the strokes is to be colored yellow--*the rest of the InkCanvas is to remain transparent*.)  Additionally, I wish to keep the strokes at the same coordinates in the target InkCanvas.

TIA

Comment: Maybe you can include an MCVE where you move the strokes to InkCanvas (1) without the yellow rectangle, so others can focus on your main problem?

Comment: @grek40 Sorry...what is MCVE?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Sorry, I assumed you know the short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you could simply add an additional bottom layer for the yellow rectangles and move your strokes from the top layer to the other layer as soon as they are created.

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas"/>
    <InkPresenter x:Name="inkPresenter"/>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" StrokeCollected="InkCanvas_StrokeCollected" Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
void InkCanvas_StrokeCollected(object sender, InkCanvasStrokeCollectedEventArgs e) {
    var stroke = e.Stroke;
    inkCanvas.Strokes.Remove(stroke);
    inkPresenter.Strokes.Add(stroke);
    var bounds = stroke.GetBounds();
    var yellowRect = new Rectangle { Width = bounds.Width, Height = bounds.Height, Fill = Brushes.Yellow };
    Canvas.SetLeft(yellowRect, bounds.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(yellowRect, bounds.Y);
    canvas.Children.Add(yellowRect);
}
```

Comment: I believe your suggestion would work except that WPF does not give access to the InkPresenter-- you need to be in universal apps to get access to the InkPresenter. However, I do see where I can change this for WPF. Thanks.

Comment: Actually WPF does give you access to the InkPresenter, if you drop the above code in a new WPF 4 project it works without any further modifications. InkPresenters are pretty useful for drawing strokes that were created elsewhere. I use them for thumbnails of sketches in my (WPF) application, amongst other things.